# Making a "not in" query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to do fairly complicated query where I can exclude items that match a certain set of conditions. Here's a super-simplified model to explain my plight:

```
class Thing(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    shared = models.BooleanField()
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

I start with a queryset that filters by User:

```
qs = Thing.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Now, from that list of Thing, I want to *exclude* any items where:

- shared is True, **and**
- number is **not** any of the values `[1, 6, 7]`.

In my head I'd do:

```
qs = qs.exclude(shared=True, number__not__in=[1, 6, 7])
```

But `__not__in` doesn't exist, does it? I feel like I need to jiggle this around to intersect two queries but that feels disgusting for something that can't be *that* complicated. What's my best way forward?

Answer (score 4):

as per discussion on IRC with op, could be

```
qs = qs.exclude( Q ( shared = True ) && ~ Q ( number__in=[1,6,7] ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

## `~Q`

That will let me do a not-query and then I can filter that by `shared=True`:

```
qs = qs.exclude(~Q(number__in=[1, 6, 7]), shared=True)
```

Comment: I m not sure if you can combine a Q expression with a non Q expression in the same filter

Comment: @karthikr You can, any Q groups have to go first though.